# Sharing live chaindata across processes

Tags: go-ethereum, pyethereum, leveldb

I'm running a node with geth, and would like to operate on the live chaindata using pyethereum. Is there a clever way to get around the lock imposed by LevelDB? Thanks!

Comment: I too would be interested in this answer. I would also like to see a way to incorporate an existing database into pyethereum.